# Enable wifi option not getting Displayed Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

The Enable wifi option which comes below enable networking option on clicking the wifi icon is not coming and I am not able to connect to wifi. I have tried running *rkfill unblock* command but I am not getting the option.I have tried restarting the PC several times and there was no effect.My wifi driver is Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel source.